# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userName') : React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to render username `userData[0].userName` it displays for the first time but if I reload it doesn't render user name.

```
const AppHeaderDropdown = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})
  const getUserData = async () => {
    debugger
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/authenticate', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
      })
      console.log(res)
      const data = await res.json()
      console.log('.........here i m in header dropdown...........')
      console.log(data[0].userName)
      setUserData(data)
      if (!res.status === 200) {
        const error = new Error(res.error)
        throw error
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData()
  }, [])
```

**TypeError**: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userName')

```
<CDropdownMenu className="pt-0" placement="bottom-end">
  61 |   <CDropdownHeader className="bg-light fw-semibold py-2">Account</CDropdownHeader>
  62 |   <CDropdownItem href="#">
> 63 |     <CIcon icon={cilUser} className="me-2" />
     | ^  64 |     {userData[0].userName}
  65 |   </CDropdownItem>
  66 |   <CDropdownItem href="#">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. The main problem is that your initial `userData` is `{}`. An empty object has no `0` property, so `userData[0]` is `undefined` on the first render. Remember that your initial state is rendered before any effects are run.
2. You're using `userData` as though it were an array, but your initial state is an empty non-array object. It should probably be `const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])` (with a `[]`, an empty array), not `const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})`.